# How to set no lock on tables in iseries/AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, informatica-powercenter

I have informatica ETL that will read the views and fetch data coming from DB2 iseries/AS400 but I have error saying "something in progress" I just want to know if there's a way in iseries to setup the view or the table with no lock so I can access the tables/views freely.

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Can you add more details regarding the error message? The exact text and/or code would be helpful to know.

Comment: The specific error code is needed because it might be unrelated to locks on a table. (Perhaps that's unlikely, but it's easily possible.) The "something" could refer to a parallel or background process that is mutually exclusive. Without an error code, we can go long way in a wrong direction.

Comment: Also, telling the **table** you want it to ignore locks is likely to have all sorts of fun repercussions.  It might not be safe to tell your process to ignore locks completely either - that's how you get stale data, after all.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure no other locks on the data can interfere with your [ETL] activity, allocate the data exclusively to your processing; e.g. one of:

`LOCK TABLE The_Schema.The_Table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE ALLOW READ`

`LOCK TABLE The_Schema.The_Table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`

After the exclusive locks [optionally allowing others read-only access] are obtained, no other locks can be obtained by other work that could otherwise conflict with your work.